# How can I add custom entries into iOS watchKit extension info.plist?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I use **info.plist** to define variables into my app and its today extension.

But I can't add those variables to the `WatchKit` **info.plist** without getting an error while building :

[image]

Am I missing something?

(xCode 7.0 beta 6)

Comment: Check your provisioning profiles and perform a restart for xcode/mac/iphone

Comment: @SilviuSt : provisionning is OK, the watchkit app start if I remove all my custom var from the Info.plist. I've just restarted the mac : same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just found my error. There are 2 **Info.plist** for the `watchKit` app.

1) The first is in the device code (directory : **Dealabs WatchKit Extension**)

2) The second is in the watch code (directory : **Dealabs WatchKit App**)

I was adding my custom vars into the watch code **Info.plist**... moving all my vars to the first solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, when you try to build it in simulator, xcode will say smth like common: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)"